# EJS changing date strings?

Tags: javascript, ejs

I found something really strange on EJS.

If you try to pass a date string argument to the template, it is changed to a random value. If I do :

```
res.render('test.ejs', {"date":"2018-5-3"})
```

Then in test.ejs:

```
console.log(<%= date %>)
```

I see in the console :

```
2010
```

It works for every date string like AAAA-M-D.

My version of EJS is 2.5.8

Comment: Looks like that crap is interpreting that as an aritmetic operation. 2018-5-3 = 2010.

Comment: Seems it's definitely a bug then. I'll post it in the issues of git.

Comment: I tried with an online ejs engine and it works fine. Weird

Comment: You can still reproduce the problem on your machine ?

Comment: didn't try in my machine.

Comment: @fazega Yup, just what I was about to comment - can't expect EJS to add quotes around strings because that would then break the HTML rendered (which is what it is usually used for). Also, it's not a big deal but the second argument to `render` is not JSON, but a JS object (no quotes around keys).

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's not really a bug.

`<%= date %>` is raw and javascript is seeing `console(2018-5-3)` so it prints 2010. Adding quotes resolved the problem.